# jQuery cycle not working/acting funny

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm working on http://www.aceaofmidland.com/ and I'm trying to use jQuery and jQuery.cycle to cycle through a wordpress custom post type that's marked up like so:

```
<div id="toolbar">
    <div id="home">
        <div id="arrows">
            <div class="prev"></div>
            <div class="next"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="descriptions">
            <div><strong>Second Home Alert Test</strong><br><p>Testing Testing Testing</p></div>
            <div><strong>Test Home Alert Title</strong><br><p>Test Content for homepage alert</p></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using the following jQuery to try and activate the cycling.  I'm positive I have the scripts correctly loaded, and in order too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function(){  
        jQuery('#descriptions').cycle({
            next: '.next',
            prev: '.prev',
            fx: 'fade',
            speed: 'fast',
            timeout: 5000,
            pause: 1
        });
    });
</script>
```

If anyone can find out how to get this to work, I'll be forever grateful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In firebug I get the following errors on pageload:

```
jQuery.cookie is not a function
http://aceaofmidland.com/
Line 126
```

and

```
$j.cookie is not a function
http://aceaofmidland.com/wp-content/themes/trademark/files/js/theme.js?ver=3.2.1
Line 570
```

You may want to change this line:

```
if(undefined != jQuery.cookie('links-variant')) {
```

to

```
if('undefined' != typeof(jQuery.cookie('links-variant'))) {
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof

And that jQuery code should probably be wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function () {});` wrapper.

I would always try to resolve all errors that occur before the code I am troubleshooting before altering the problematic code itself.

Comment: Technically `jQuery(function(){});` is the same as `jQuery(document).ready(function(){});`, and I'm unsure as to whether the cookie errors should be stopping the plugin, but you are correct, I'll try to resolve the jquery.cookie issues and get back with you on whether it helps my case or not.  Thank you.

Comment: And of course as usual, removing the calls for jquery.cookie.js and removing some other lines that had to do with it, the errors are no longer there and the cycle works great.  I had been half-inspecting the DOM but didn't think anything of the cookie errors.  Anyways, thanks for pointing out my mistakes. Everything works great now!